# c# dollar to euro conversion is always returning 0

Tags: c#, json, webclient, clipboard

I am trying to make a dollar to euro converter. but strangely enough, it always returns 0. The intention is that the user, for example, `10 dollars to euro` and then the result comes out how much 10 dollars than currently is in euros this is my code what I have at the moment.

**This is my current code**

```
            public void EUR_TO_usd(string clipboardText)
            {
                ActionResult actionResult = new ActionResult(clipboardText);
                if (clipboardText.EndsWith(" dollar to euro"))
                {
                    var parts = clipboardText.Split(' ');
                    if (parts.Length == 4)
                    {
                        if (double.TryParse(parts[0], out double amount))
                        {
                            if (parts[1] == "dollar" && parts[2] == "to" && parts[3] == "euro")
                            {
                                string url = "http://api.openrates.io/latest?base=USD";
                                string json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
                                var currency = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
                                double curAmount = amount * Convert.ToSingle(currency.rates.EUR);
                                actionResult.Title = clipboardText;
                                actionResult.Description = string.Format("{0:N2} {1} = {2:N2} {3}", amount, currency["base"], curAmount, "EUR");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

the only thing that worked was putting this in a switch and creating a variable amount with a value like this

```
                case "dollar to euro":
                    {
                        string url = "http://api.openrates.io/latest?base=USD";
                        string json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
                        var amount = 1;
                        var currency = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
                        double curAmount = amount * (double)currency.rates.EUR;
                        {
                            actionResult.Title = clipboardText;
                            actionResult.Description = $"{amount:N2} {currency.@base} = {curAmount:N2} EUR";
                        }
                    }
                    return actionResult;
```

but what I want is that the user can copy the number of euros as in my first example, but that always returns 0.
How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you try debugging this? Is the correct amount read from your `clipboardText`? Is the `currency.rates.EUR` what you expect? How is that local variable `actionResult` used in your void method (right now it seems you set it and ignore it)?

Comment: After making sure the text ends with " dollar to euro" and that splitting results in 4 values, making sure the last three are "dollar" "to" and "euro" is pointless.

Comment: what should i do then @juharr

Comment: Remove that last `if` since by that point it will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but it doesn't seem like you are changing the actionResult, but only the title and description. And if you would want to just return a int i would use `public int EUR_TO_usd()`
And i would look into the naming convention in C#, since a function name shoud **not** look like that imo.

And of course you need to call your function with that string.